# PHP - MySQL queries refusing to execute

Tags: php, mysql, execute

I have the following code:

```
<?php

$usStates = array(
    'Alabama',
    'Alaska',
    'Arizona',
    'Arkansas',
    'California',
    'Colorado',
    'Connecticut',
    'Delaware',
    'Florida',
    'Georgia',
    'Hawaii',
    'Idaho',
    'Illinois',
    'Indiana',
    'Iowa',
    'Kansas',
    'Kentucky',
    'Louisiana',
    'Maine',
    'Maryland',
    'Massachusetts',
    'Michigan',
    'Minnesota',
    'Mississippi',
    'Missouri',
    'Montana',
    'Nebraska',
    'Nevada',
    'New Hampshire',
    'New Jersey',
    'New Mexico',
    'New York',
    'North Carolina',
    'North Dakota',
    'Ohio',
    'Oklahoma',
    'Oregon',
    'Pennsylvania',
    'Rhode Island',
    'South Carolina',
    'South Dakota',
    'Tennessee',
    'Texas',
    'Utah',
    'Vermont',
    'Virginia',
    'Washington',
    'West Virginia',
    'Wisconsin',
    'Wyoming',
);

$link = new mysqli("localhost", "drup197", "*******", "census");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}


foreach ($usStates as $state) {
    printf("Entering loop\n");
    printf("Current state = %s\n", $state);

    if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE '$state'_age_and_gender_demographics LIKE national_age_and_gender_demographics")) {
        printf("%s_age_and_gender_demographics successfully created\n", $state);
    }
    if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE '$state'_race_demographics_-_one_race LIKE national_race_demographics_-_one_race")) {
        printf("%s_race_demographics_-_one_race successfully craeted\n");
    }
    if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE '$state'_race_demographics_-_multi-race LIKE national_race_demographics_-_multi-race")) {
        printf("%s_race_demographics_-_multi-race successfully craeted\n");
    }
    if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE '$state'_race_demographics_-_hispanic_or_latino LIKE national_race_demographics_-_hispanic_or_latino")) {
        printf("%s_race_demographics_-_hispanic_or_latino successfully craeted\n");
    }
}
printf("Tables successfuly created");

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Basically, I am trying to create tables for all 50 states, using the name of the state as a wildcard for the name of the tables.  However, these queries don't appear to be executing.  Could you please let me know the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the single quotes from your query strings.  You're trying to create tables called  **'California'_age_and_gender_demographics**.

Or try:

```
if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE ". $state ."_age_and_gender_demographics LIKE national_age_and_gender_demographics")) {
    printf("%s_age_and_gender_demographics successfully created\n", $state);
}
if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE ". $state ."_race_demographics_-_one_race LIKE national_race_demographics_-_one_race")) {
    printf("%s_race_demographics_-_one_race successfully craeted\n");
}
if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE ". $state ."_race_demographics_-_multi-race LIKE national_race_demographics_-_multi-race")) {
    printf("%s_race_demographics_-_multi-race successfully craeted\n");
}
if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE ". $state ."_race_demographics_-_hispanic_or_latino LIKE national_race_demographics_-_hispanic_or_latino")) {
    printf("%s_race_demographics_-_hispanic_or_latino successfully craeted\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  For some reason, however, only the first query executed.  I wonder why the others are not executing.

Comment: Okay, I see my problem now, the hyphens were causing these queries to fail.  I have since removed the hyphens from the table names and got these queries to successfully work.